# Mysql on duplicate key update with multiple keys (one primary key and one unique key with multiple columns) Dapper

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-core-3.1

The table structure is `Id(Guid) | Name(string) | Date(Date) | Address(string)`

with constraints `PRIMARY KEY (Id), UNIQUE KEY Rec_Unique (Name,Date)`

I am trying to insert or update if duplicate key. I am using dapper and ExecuteAsync is returning rows effected as 1 or sometime 2.

**How to make it return 0 instead when keys exists** I think it is looking at Id and during insert but I want it to look at both id and (name, date) before updating

The query I am executing using dapper is

```
insert into exam (Id, Name, Date, Address) 
values (@Id, @Name, @Date, @Address) 
on duplicate key update Date = @Date, Address= @Address
```

Comment: *How to make it return 0 instead.* Why? The row is either inserted (1 row affected) or updated (2 rows affected). If zero rows affected then the error occures.

Comment: "*I think it is looking at Id and during insert but I want it to look at both id and (name, date) before updating*". It does look at both, but your data cannot violate both (as then, MySQL wouldn't know which of the two rows to update). Also be aware that, if the id exists, it will currently not update the name! (e.g. if you insert "1, leela, today, mars", and "1, krishna, yesterday, pluto" exists (key violation for id=1), that row will change to "1, krishna, today, mars", not "1, leela, today, mars". But this has nothing to do with the return value of 0/1/2.